# Stop JScrollPane from high amount of redraws when scrolling

Tags: java, performance, swing, jscrollpane

I have long text in Text Area placed to the Scroll Pane. I've noticed that when I rotate the mouse wheel, the text is redrawn severely, maybe even entirely.

This is the demo app:

```java
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class TextArea {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    final JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
    textArea.setColumns(80);
    textArea.setRows(20);
    textArea.setLineWrap(true);
    final JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);
    textArea.append("1234567890 ".repeat(20000));  // Java 11
    frame.add(scrollPane);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

Redrawing can be easily detected if you place a logging breakpoint to the `sun.java2d.SunGraphics2D.drawString(String, float, float)` method. For me, it logs a couple of thousands hits when I rotate mouse wheel by a single unit (the number of hits depends on the size of frame). If I stop at breakpoint, I see that `y` position of the string to draw differs a lot and the difference is much more than the height of my screen.

I think it should better redraw only visible lines, or maybe even newly appeared lines.

Can `JScrollPane` be set up somehow to optimize the amount of draw calls? Or is it an unoptimized thing in Swing?

Comment: "it logs a couple of thousands hits when I rotate mouse wheel by a single unit " How many does it log for a single repaint? You have a pretty big chunk of text in there, not sure how many strings that works out to be. Does it check the string bounds inside of that method? So it will try to draw all strings for a single repaint.

Comment: @matt, I will check `frame.repaint()` tomorrow and publish the result.

Comment: That still doesn't make sense. Your JScrollPane is causing your JTextArea to repaint possibly one time, maybe two or three at the most. You have picked a method to follow. "drawString" which of course gets called a lot, because your text area has a lot of strings. Frame.repaint has nothing to do with it. Maybe you should start by going through the java2d drawing tutorials and learning how swing painting works.

Comment: @matt, I don't understand what I should check then. So I've checked what I intended. When I just open the app, there are about 5K calls of drawString. When I scroll down by a single scroll unit, there are about 1700 more. Then I scrolled 10 times and got about 17000 calls. Under debug, I see that every call contains quite a long string to render, it's crazy: why there are too many? Could you please clarify what you mean under "learning how swing painting works"? Do you mean that Swing is indeed not optimal and I can't do anything here?

Comment: No, I mean you have a lot of strings, so when it repaints, it tries to repaint all of them. You're measuring the number of times "drawString" is called, but that doesn't represent the number of times the TextArea is repainted. "Do you mean that Swing is indeed not optimal and I can't do anything here?" I mean, you don't understand enough to say what is optimal about it and what isn't.

Comment: Is there a performance issue? From the posted code you have a long line of text that needs to wrap. So I would guess the logic is doing the wrapping every time? What happens if you use: `textArea.append("1234567890 \n".repeat(20000));` so that each line of text is on a new line?

Comment: @camickr, wow, thanks, without wrapping it's really much faster! I see only about 50 `drawString` calls at the app start and about five `drawString`s each time when I scroll. Not sure why it redraws too much when wrapping is happening, to me it seems like a bug: it could just calculate the distances without redrawing and draw only needed parts...

Comment: A string cannot be drawn on more than one line. When you have wrapping, then your big long string gets split into a bunch of strings 80 characters long to be drawn. This has nothing to do with the scroll pane though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`JTextArea` indeed generates too much draw calls for a long line, seems like it redraws it fully and because of soft wrapping, it's split.

However, going deeper, it's visible that while scrolling, clipping area is set quite restrictively (to the newly visible space), so Graphics2D is able to skip drawing of all the strings that are outside of clipping.

So there is no need to worry because actually not much drawing should be performed.

Answer (score 0):

When I run this code and spin the mouse scroll wheel, the GUI doesn't flicker or change at all.  The only reason I see my scroll wheel doing something is the `JScrollPane` tab moves upward.

I compiled to the Java 8 standard, using Java 14.0.2.  My computer runs on Windows 10.

Not surprising, since the text is identical.

Try this complete runnable code and see if it makes a difference.

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class LargeTextArea implements Runnable {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new LargeTextArea());
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        
        final JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
        textArea.setColumns(80);
        textArea.setRows(20);
        textArea.setLineWrap(true);
        textArea.append("1234567890 ".repeat(20000)); // Java 11
        
        final JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);
        frame.add(scrollPane);
        
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: By redrawing I mean not flickering, but usage of computation...